# Parse response into a model object in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

If I have a REST call to some server like this :

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get<PersonEntry>(`somehost/personentry`)
          .then(res => {
            // Can I slice res.data into result ? 
            const result : PersonEntry = res.data; 
            this.setState(result)
          })
      }
```

And let's say I have a PersonEntry model object :

```
 export class PersonEntry {
    name: string = '';
    address: string = ''; 
    PersonEntry(){} 
}
```

How can I "slice" the response into this object without cherry picking the fields if the response contains a lot of fields I want to ignore ? Now I will just get all the fields from the response into my PersonEntry object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can map only properties, which needed:

```
const result = response.map(obj => ({name: obj.name, address: obj.address}));
```

So, in `console.log(result)` You will have only parameters, which you select.

later:

```
const final : PersonEntry = result;
```

It works?

Comment: No, response.map(obj => ({name: obj.name, address: obj.address})) gives "property map does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any>'"

Comment: I am also wondering if it is possible to slice into the PersonEntry object without cherrypicking the fields, and make any field match iff it matches.

Comment: Can you provide me all code - i try to replicate it in my machine.

Comment: Probably the response data isn't objects - so i need schema from backend.

Comment: I tried with response.data.map insatead, and yes, you are right, it's not an array, and I can see that map is for arrays, and can't be  used for objects. I have to find a nother way to map the object that I receive, but I am not quite sure how

Comment: If i know the structure/schema of your backend response I can prepare map to assing to result variable.

Comment: Because res.data is a PersonEntry response object, and not an array, I am using a transform like so (the transform does all the mapping) :     componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`host/someResource`)
          .then(res => {
            let entry : PersonEntry = PersonEntryTransform.transform(res.data);
            this.setState(entry)
          })
      } That works. What do you think ?

Comment: If it works - great. What is the PersonEntryTransform?

Comment: A PersonEntry has a builder, and the PersonEntryTransform takes the received object and builds and returns a PersonEntry, like in this manner, eg :          if ('name' in response && response['name'] != null) {
            builder.name(response['name']);
        }
        I don't want to use "assign", because I want to have control over the fields and use an internal model object in React. What do you think ?